# how to integrate twitter login with code igniter

Tags: codeigniter

In my site i want to integrate twitter log in.There is also a normal log in, if users use the twitter log in,they should log in to that site.How it is possible with codeigniter.

Comment: This is a very broad question, you need to provide some details about how your current login system works as the big part of it is intergrating with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. http://dev.twitter.com/start
2. https://github.com/ericbae/Tank-Auth---3rd-Party-Authentication-Project

Answer (score 0):

```
<iframe src="http://twitter.com/#!/login">
```

??

Not sure what you're looking for. If they use the twitter login they log on to twitter? And leave your site? If so, an iframe should work. If you want them to log onto your site with twitter credentials... that's a different story.

Clarify what you need.